# Adding list item and getting NullReferenceException C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have the following model:

```
public static class AttachmentsList {
    public static List<AttachmentDetails> AttachmentPath { get; set; }
}

public class AttachmentDetails {
    public string AttachmentPath { get; set; }
    public string AttachmentName { get; set; }
    public MediaFile MediaFileObject { get; set; }
}
```

I wanted to add items `AttachmentPath` but I'm getting `object reference not set to an instance of an object` when using the following code:

```
AttachmentDetails attachmentDetails = new AttachmentDetails();

attachmentDetails.AttachmentName = attachmentsViewModel.GetFileName(mediaFile.Path);
attachmentDetails.AttachmentPath = mediaFile.Path;
attachmentDetails.MediaFileObject = mediaFile;

AttachmentsList.AttachmentPath.Add(attachmentDetails);
```

Comment: Did you instantiate your list somewhere? You need to instantiate before you can add objects to it. `AttachmentsList.AttachmentPath = new List<AttachmentDetails>();`

Comment: @Chronicle this works. Thank you. Being a beginner, is it okay if I ask the logic behind it?

Comment: Your code `public static List<AttachmentDetails> AttachmentPath { get; set; }` creates a property named AttachmentPath, creates a hidden field and creates a *Getter* and a *Setter* that provides public access to that private hidden. That hidden field is a reference to a `List<AD>`. They getter & setter provide typed access to that field. But, a reference to an instance of a reference type has a default value of `null`. If you don't initialize it, it stays null, and if you use it before you initialize it, boom, a null ref exception